# Different results when using different cl.exe compiler options

Tags: visual-c++, sse, inline-assembly, fpu, x87

I'm on Windows 7 64bit, using VS2013 Express for Desktop.

Compile as default (using SSE)

```
D:\Work>cl printf-test.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86

D:\Work>printf-test.exe
FPU control word 0x0000037f
0. FPU status 0x00000000
1. 0x43380000 0x00000000
1. FPU status 0x00000000
2. 0x43380000 0x00000001
2. FPU status 0x00000000
3. 0x43380000 0x00000001          //@@1
3. FPU status 0x00000000
```

Compile using x87 only.

```
D:\Work>cl /arch:IA32 printf-test.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86

D:\Work>printf-test.exe
FPU control word 0x0000037f
0. FPU status 0x00000000
1. 0x43380000 0x00000000
1. FPU status 0x00000020
2. 0x43380000 0x00000001   
2. FPU status 0x00000220
3. 0x43380000 0x00000000         //@@1 this is the difference. why?
3. FPU status 0x00000020
```

Test code as below

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_double_hex( double d , int idx)
{
    union UD
    {
        double d;
        int i[2];
    } c;
    c.d = d + 6755399441055744.0;
    printf("%d. 0x%08x 0x%08x\n", idx, c.i[1], c.i[0]);
}

void PrintControlWord()
{
    int a;
    int c;
    __asm {
        fstcw [esp - 4]
        mov eax, [esp - 4]
        and eax, 0xFFFF
        mov c, eax
    }
    printf("FPU control word 0x%08x\n", c);
}

void PrintStatus(int idx)
{
    int a;
    int c;
    __asm {
        fstsw [esp - 4]
        mov eax, [esp - 4]
        and eax, 0xFFFF
        mov c, eax
    }
    printf("%d. FPU status 0x%08x\n", idx, c);
}

int main()
{
    double a = .5;
    double b = 0.501;
    double c = 0.5001;
    int fpu = 0;

    __asm {                 // @@2 Remove it, see result below
        finit
    }

    PrintControlWord();
    PrintStatus(0); 

    print_double_hex(a, 1);
    PrintStatus(1); 

    print_double_hex(b, 2);
    PrintStatus(2);

    print_double_hex(c, 3);
    PrintStatus(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that I initialize the FPU manually, if I remove it. The result will change!

After removing `finit`, Compile as default

```
D:\Work>cl printf-test.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86

D:\Work>printf-test.exe
FPU control word 0x0000027f      //@@2 FPU control word changed, why?
0. FPU status 0x00000000
1. 0x43380000 0x00000000
1. FPU status 0x00000000
2. 0x43380000 0x00000001
2. FPU status 0x00000000
3. 0x43380000 0x00000001
3. FPU status 0x00000000
```

Compile using x87 only

```
D:\Work>cl /arch:IA32 printf-test.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.21005.1 for x86

D:\Work>printf-test.exe
FPU control word 0x0000027f
0. FPU status 0x00000000
1. 0x43380000 0x00000000
1. FPU status 0x00000020
2. 0x43380000 0x00000001
2. FPU status 0x00000020
3. 0x43380000 0x00000001         //@@3, why?
3. FPU status 0x00000020
```

So my questions is:

1. For `@@1`, why there are different? Is it a bug?
2. For `@@3`, why the value changed?

Comment: SSE math (including scalar of course) uses MXCSR for control/status, totally separate from the legacy x87 control and status words.